# Create Style Programmatically

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I have a requirement to display a theme that comes from a webservice (return the color etc). What I want to know is can I create a style programmatically? I have my code setup to incorporate theme and I have 2 themes defined in xml which work perfectly fine. And now I want to add a third theme which is not locally in an xml. Is this even possible?

The other approach to achieve this is to create custom classes for views and apply the style according to the theme. Which is I don't want to do, as it is very tedious and error prone.

Any other suggestions are welcomed as well.

Comment: I have found no way to create a theme entirely programmatically. You may have to make some classes that apply colors to views, or you could create several themes and choose which theme based on what the server tells you.

Comment: @Farooq Arshad - For your query, what approach you had followed for the solution? Because I am also having the same concern as you had. Could you please share your experience with me.

Comment: @MohammadMisbah I ended up creating custom classes for views and implemented the theme inside the classes. Apologies for late reply.

Comment: @FarooqArshed - Thank you so kind response.